# «Парад тюльпанов в ботсаду»

Tags: прописная-строчная, прописная

С большой буквы слово «парад»? Конкретный парад в Ялте. А парад цветов? Просто, без привязки к месту.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пишут по-разному, например:

*В Никитском ботаническом саду открылось красочное мероприятие – 15-й по счёту **парад тюльпанов**. Сейчас в Никитском ботсаду в Ялте идет **Парад тюльпанов**. В Никитском ботсаду в Крыму стартовал **"Парад тюльпанов"**.*

В принципе допустимы все варианты, но в разных ситуациях. Парады тюльпанов проводятся в различных городах и странах, и тогда это нарицательное сочетание – ***парад тюльпанов.***

Выражение ***15-й по счёту парад тюльпанов*** тоже верно, здесь также нарицательный смысл.

Когда речь идет о конкретном мероприятии в данном городе и там уже есть определенные традиции и правила, то можно считать название праздника **именем собственным**.

Разные записи (с кавычками и без них) – это скорее **авторский выбор**. *Парад тюльпанов* – можно без кавычек, но чем длиннее название, тем кавычки уместнее:
*Парад тюльпанов, "Парад тюльпанов в ботсаду".*